# Extracting Sub Sequence from a file - Java - Fast Way

Tags: java

I have a large file which contains sequence of characters like "ABCDEabcde.....XYZxyz". Now, I want to extract some sub-sequences of it. Say for example from 10 th character to 50 th character, from 15 th character to 55 th character (all sub-sequences has same length and starting position is always increasing). Can anybody help me how to do that in a fast way in Java ?

Comment: Any suggestion, which way is the faster one ?

Comment: What are we picking from? What have you tried? What is your expected runtime environment? what is the size limits on the input file? any restrictions on the subsequence size?

Comment: @ColinD  We are picking sub-sequence of fixed length  for example a file content "My Name is", I want to extract sub sequence from position 1 to 3, i.e. "My ".

Comment: @ColinD, "any restrictions on the subsequence size" yah. all sub sequence size are equal length i.e. 40 characters.

Comment: @ColinD,"what is the size limits on the input file?" approx. 700 MB.

Comment: When you say its a large file, can I assume it has a million lines?

Comment: @noMAD, It has more than million lines.

Comment: @Arpssss: I have one more question, do you have a particular set of subStrings which you want to extract before hand or can they be dynamic? I ask this cause, if the subStrings required are set, then you don't need to load the entire file to memory.

Comment: @noMAD, they are dynamic, for example in one run from 1 t0 41 & 3 to 43 but in another run 5 to 45 & 10 to 50. But, always incremental (i.e. (1,3...) and (5,10..)) and fixed length subStrings i.e. 40 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<FileName>), int size);
```

Just input the buffer size there and keep checking for your `subStrings` in that chunk alone. If nothing is found, discard it and go to the next chunk.

Comment: Actually, I thought it. But, it should be slow. I am finding a faster one approach than common Buffered Reader, File Reader etc. for doing this. Can say a faster in-built one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MappedByteBuffer and access file as a byte buffer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(....);
FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();

MappedByteBuffer mmap = fc.map(READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size() );
```

Comment: So does this load the entire file to a `ByteBuffer`and stores it till it the garbage collector is called?

Comment: I just check it, it will load entire file in memory. For me it's impossible. However, thanks a lot.

Comment: you can load only required parts - just call map() for required parts of the file