# Java- Dynamic Sub String Extraction from File - Fast Way

Tags: java, guava

I have a large file which contains sequence of characters like "ABCDEabcde.....XYZxyz". Now, I want to extract some sub-sequence string from it. Say for example from 10 th character to 50 th character string, from 15 th character to 55 th character string (all sub-sequences string has same length i.e. 40 chars and starting position (e.g 10,15) is always increasing). Sub-sequence positions are dynamic means in one run from 10 to 50 th character, from 15 to 55 character, in another run from 2 to 42 th character and from 100 to 140 th character. Now, I have to extract millions of such dynamic sub-strings. I have tried some methods as suggested to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355898/extracting-sub-sequence-from-a-file-java-fast-way). However, they are quite slow for me.

I have tried:

1) Use BufferedReader for simple buffered reading, and wait for the required position chunk.

2) Use Random Access File and Seek method to do that.

As my file is about 700 mb (nearly 200 millions of chars) and I have to extract millions of such dynamic sub-strings, they take nearly a minute for me (1st one takes more). Can anybody help me by providing any other idea which maybe faster than it ? Using any Java library is also OK for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient thing you can do is map the whole file into memory. Basically:

```
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
```

I don't think there's anything more efficient you can try - modern OSes optimize memory mapped files quite well.

Comment: "map the whole file" - I have 700 mb file. And my memory is limited means used by lots of other threads and data structures. 700 mb file is too large to fit in main memory.

Comment: @Arpsss Nobody says that the OS will allocate 700mb physical memory for the file - actually no OS I know of does that. You just need enough virtual memory, which can be a problem in 32bit processes. NIO is quite sparse with the actual information, exactly because that's a quite low level process depending on the OS. [Windows docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) - if you have linux the manpages for mmap should help as well.

Comment: I have 64 bit. No issue with that. But how to extract sub-sequences ?

Comment: I have linux server, so that will be really helpful.

Comment: @Arpsss If you've never worked with NIO and bytebuffers before you'll have to read some short tutorial about those - they're not completely straight forward (usual for low level stuff), but not too complicated.

Comment: Means for extracting sub-sequences I have to perform some manipulations ? Actually, I never worked with NIO and byte-buffer.

Comment: @Arpsss [This](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffers.shtml) tutorial looks like it should explain the basics good enough. You should be fine with a charbuffer and the get functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I as also thinking to do it using char buffer using charAt method. See what happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way would be to just load the whole file in memory and extract the required substrings from there. It will eat a lot of memory, but it will be much faster (which is what you're aiming at).

Comment: "load the whole file" - I have 700 mb file. And my memory is limited means used by lots of other threads and data structures. 700 mb file is too large to fit in main memory